# Different Login for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress website I am using one directory plugin (Sabai Directory) and WooCommerce.

Now when user register for directory, users are able to use same login detail for WooCommerce (shopping) or if a user buy and product and register at the time of shopping , he is able to user same login on directory.

I want different login for directory and shopping . Means different database user table for both .

If a user register for directory he will not able to use same login for WooCommerce .

Please help me ! If there is any plugin that create separate table for WooCommerce registration , that will be great .

Comment: Is there a reason why they need to be in a different table. I'm *fairly* certain WooCommerce has a specific user role (and if they didn't be default there should be a plugin out there). If that role doesn't have backend access then it's (semi)irrelevant that it's in the same table as the admins.

Comment: Actually my directory is for certain users like doctors , so I dont want that my buyers will also able to post on that directory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress the list of all users is maintained in table wp_users. User role/capability can differ ( like by default woocommerce registers a user as "customer" ). So it doesn't matter whether you register through woocommerce or anything else, all users will end up at same place unless the third-party plugin you are using is maintaining separate table or other mechanism for users.

**Conclusion:**
You can have different login for directory and shopping, iff "Sabai Directory" plugin maintains separate user record (Woocommerce does not). Or develop a plugin that does the thing you need :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) issue. you'll need to [add a capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) for doctors and then on all your doctors pages add

```
if (!current_user_can('doctors') {
    echo 'You shouldn't be here;
} else {
    //doctor page stuff
}
```

to your pages that you want doctors to view but not shoppers.

Depending on how complex you need it you may need to even add a [role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

Comment: you could also do the inverse for the woocommerce users, or do both.